# trigger save_post event programmatically

Tags: hooks, actions, save-post, events

Is there a way to trigger the post saving or updating event in code? such as `do_action('save_post', $post_id)`;
The function here seems to imply that a WP_POST object needs to be passed in. Is there a way to basically imitate the action of updating the post with all its existing values. The point is for the other hooks linked to all trigger on post update. Maybe do a `wp_insert_post()`, just passing in the post id?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/
`do_action( 'save_post', int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update )`

Comment: Not quite following "other hooks linked to all trigger" - could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? It sounds like more than just adding a new revision to the db.

Comment: I want to trigger all  the hooks hooked to save_post that's why I'd like to trigger the event somehow.

Comment: What is your goal in triggering all of the hooks? If you explain a bit more we may be able to help you think of another solution that's cleaner.

Comment: Other plugins have hooks linked to save_post that I want to trigger.

Comment: why you don't want to use the function `wp_insert_post` ?

Comment: I can do that do that? How do I pass in the original values. If I just pass in the post_id, would that work?

Comment: look at the codex to learn how to use it : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/

Comment: @mmm That's not helpful at all...

Answer (score 0):

It's [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) vs.
[`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) - where update will ultimately also call:

```
return wp_insert_post( $postarr, $wp_error, $fire_after_hooks );
```

The term "once" implies that it is being fired "afterwards".

```
/**
 * Fires once a post has been saved.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
 * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
 * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated.
 */
do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );
```

When inserting a post, `save_post` is being fired while `$fire_after_hooks` is `true`.
And usually one may want to insert/update the record and not only fire the hook ...

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question - you're implying they need to pass a $poastarr in, when OP is asking if you can save existing values as is.

Comment: @AlxVallejo `do_action('save_post', $post_id)` is non-sense, when no data is being passed (one can register whatever one wants). But there's generally not much use in firing hooks, without the corresponding data payload. I mean, `$post_ID` should refer to an existing post.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is to call `do_action` with the correct parameters. However, I would like to know more about why you're doing this - is there a post your saving programmatically?

Comment: There are multiple hooks in the system related to save_post event that I want to trigger for the posts.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. The best way to trigger all the actions related to save post is to call either wp_insert_post or wp_update_post

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it doesn't provide much insight into the problem and it could just as well have been a comment rather than an answer.